# What are the different types of firewall protections available for a WordPress website?

Tags: security

Can someone please explain **(in layman language)** what are the different types of firewall protections available for a WP site.

How do these firewall work and how are they different from one another?

If you think one offers better protection than the other, tell me why?

Answer (score 1):

There is no "WordPress Firewall".

A [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) acts either on the network or on the host, never on a later stage such as a specific software running on a server.

Everything that claims to be a firewall specific for WordPress is a scam. See the linked Wikipedia article for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Let me first tell you how the firewall work. Firewall acts as a shield between your wordpress website and all incoming traffic from all over the world. Firewalls monitor your website traffic and blocks many common security threats before they reach your WordPress site.

There are two type of firewall protection available for WP site.
1) DNS Level Website Firewall
2) Application Level Firewall

Now let me give brief how are they different from one another.
**DNS Level Website Firewall** – These firewall route your website traffic through their cloud proxy servers. This allows them to only send genuine traffic to your web server.

**Application Level Firewall** – These firewall examine the traffic once it reaches your server but before loading most WordPress scripts. This method is not as efficient as DNS level firewall in reducing the server load.

and finally i recommend using a DNS level firewall because they are exceptionally good at identifying genuine website traffic vs bad requests